# What is the best way to create same Views in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sometimes I need to create same Views (or ImageViews) in Swift.

For example, make same size and image, delete the view, and make it again (and sometimes change the view's image or size).

In this case, of course writing same codes each time to need the view is not good.
So I want to find good way to create same views multiple times.

Now I use this code when I create same ImageView.

***CreateImage.swift**

```
class aImageView: UIImageView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let aImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 50))
        aImageView.image = UIImage(named: "item_a01_70x50")
        aImageView.tag = 100
        aImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        aImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.addSubview(aImageView)

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

}

class bImageView: UIImageView {
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            let bImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 50))
            bImageView.image = UIImage(named: "item_b02_70x50")
            bImageView.tag = 200
            bImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            bImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            self.addSubview(bImageView)

        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        }

    }
```

***TopView.swift**

```
    class TopView: UIView {

        var aview: aImageView!
        var bview: bImageView!

        init(frame: CGRect, stage:Int){
            super.init(frame: frame)

            aview = aImageView(frame :CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 50))
            self.addSubview(aview)

            bview = bImageView(frame :CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 70, height: 50))
            self.addSubview(bview)

            //...and sometimes delete them, create them again other time, and create...

        }
    }
```

If you know better way, could you tell me?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, you are right, this is definitely not the way to do it. You can just define one view class and create instances of it each time you need a new view. You dont need to define a new class. I would suggest you can refresh your Object Oriented programming basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can make an extension of `UIImageView` like this:

```
extension UIImageView {
    convenience init(_imageName: String = "", 
                    _frameTulpe: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) = (0, 0, 0, 0), 
                           _tag: Int = 0, 
      _isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool = true, 
               _backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray) 
    {
        self.init(image: UIImage(named: _imageName))

        frame = CGRect(x: _frameTulpe.x, y: _frameTulpe.y, width: _frameTulpe.w, height: _frameTulpe.h)
        tag = _tag
        isUserInteractionEnabled = _isUserInteractionEnabled
        backgroundColor = _backgroundColor
    }
}
```

And then, in your `TopView.swift` will be:

```
class TopView: UIView {

    var aview: aImageView!
    var bview: bImageView!

    init(frame: CGRect, stage:Int){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        aview = UIImageView(_imageName: "item_a01_70x50", _frameTulpe:(0, 0, 70, 50), _tag: 100)
        self.addSubview(aview)

        bview = UIImageView(_imageName: "item_b02_70x50", _frameTulpe:(100, 100, 70, 50), _tag: 200)
        self.addSubview(bview)

        //...and sometimes delete them, create them again other time, and create...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uh hun! You just need merge the aImageView class and bImageView class. Then the variable property can be set after that the object be created, or you can define the other init method with it is contain the different parameter that be used for initializing the variable property.

Comment: Thank you. If you like, could you give me sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

Define just one class(**ex: Utility.swift**) which will provide custom Views.
Last but not the least you need to **autolayout** after adding subview(ex: **aImageView**).
I am following this technique.

Comment: Thank your for answering. If you like, could you give me the sample codes? I don't know how to provide custom views... and in now my codes, when I touch the imageView, I couldn't get the view tag...